# How to get the orginal entity instance on the client side?

Tags: wcf-ria-services

Suppose I have an entity person which has been modified on the client side.

Then I want the original person before it was modified. How can I do that on the client side before I submit the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the original state of an entity with `MyEntity.GetOriginal()` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.entity.getoriginal(v=vs.91).aspx